# Округлить decimal(15,2) в большую сторону

Tags: c, db2

Есть нужда округлить `decimal(15,2)` до `decimal(15,1)` обязательно в большую сторону средствами С. Пример: `40.61 -> 40.7`. Как это сделать?

---

**Update:** Стоило сказать, что у меня подключен `#include <decimal.h>`. Там лежит описание типа, который соответствует `decimal(x,y)` в DB2

Comment: прибавить 0.09 и округлить вниз. вниз по идее должно быть округление

Comment: @D-side Собственно, объявлен как `decimal(15,2) variable;` Десятичное число с фиксированной точкой. Вмещает 13 знаков до запятой и 2 после.

Comment: @D-side: Может быть, вопрос на самом деле по какому-то диалекту SQL?

Comment: @D-side: Угу, мистика какая-то.

Comment: @D-side Верно. Стоило сказать, что у меня подключен `#include <decimal.h>`. Там лежит описание типа, который соответствует `decimal(x,y)` в DB2. Тогда моя проблема несколько специфичнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться стандартной функцией `round`:

```
double round1(double x) {
    x *= 10;
    double r = round(x);
    if (x > r)
        r += 1;
    return r / 10;
}
```

А можно `floor`:

```
double round2(double x) {
    x *= 10;
    double r = floor(x);
    if (r < x)
       r += 1;
    return r / 10;
}
```

А можно не мучиться и вызвать `ceil`:

```
double round3(const double x) {
    return ceil(x * 10) / 10;
}
```